# Splitting ADODB Recordset to Excel worksheet?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have a small macro program that extracts almost 2 million rows of data from SQL to Excel worksheet. But the problem is, each worksheet can only contain up to 1048576 rows, so it cuts my data.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to split the ADODB Recordset before you paste it to Excel.

Here's my code for extracting the data from SQL to Excel:

```
With oRecordSet
    .ActiveConnection = oDBConnection
    .Source = MySql
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .Open
End With
Sheets("Data)").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset oRecordSet
```

Appreciate your help guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is "paging".

Comment: I am not familiar with VBA but i got your point. How about if you use a limit of your script then remember the last record or insert the last record whatever you want to do for it. then paste or copy the other record into another sheet. After the first execution has been done.

Answer (score 0):

You can [query the data and apply some filtering logic](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Microsoft-Query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e).

You can try [delimit](http://www.delimitware.com/), and manage up to 100 million rows.

Or, use a file splitting tool (like [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simpletextsplit/) or [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-split-a-huge-csv-excel-workbook-into-seperate-files/)).

You can try a VBA solution as well.

**step1**

Save As, your Workbook with extension .xlsm (macros enabled)

**step2**

1. press <kbd>ALT + F11</kbd> to open Visual Basic
2. Insert > module and paste the code below on the right (from `Sub`....`End Sub`)

```vb
Sub SplitTxt_01()

    Const HelperFile As String = "ABCD" '<<< temp. helper text file Name
    Const N As Long = 700000  '<<< split each txt in N rows, CHANGE
    Dim myPath
    myPath = "c:\Folder1\Folder2\" '<<< folder path, CHANGE
    Dim myFile
    myFile = "Data File.TXT" '<<< your text file. CHANGE txt file name as needed

    Dim WB As Workbook, myWB As Workbook
    Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
    Dim myWS As Worksheet
    Dim t As Long, r As Long
    Dim myStr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'split text file in separate text files
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myFile)
    Open myPath & myFile For Input As #1
    t = 1
    r = 1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, myStr
    If r > N Then
    t = t + 1
    r = 1
    End If
    Open myPath & HelperFile & t & ".txt" For Append As #2
    Print #2, myStr
    Close #2
    r = r + 1
    Loop
    Close #1

    'copy txt files in separate sheets
    For i = t To 1 Step -1
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=myPath & HelperFile & i & ".txt", DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set myWS = myWB.Sheets.Add
    myWS.Name = HelperFile & i
    rng.Copy myWS.Cells(1, 1)
    WB.Close False
    Next
    myWB.Save

    'Delete helper txt files
    Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Fldr = Fso.GetFolder(myPath)
    For Each Filename In Fldr.Files
    If Filename Like "*" & HelperFile & "*" Then Filename.Delete
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

3. Press <kbd>ALT + Q</kbd> to Close Visual Basic

As a final thought, I'll say it may be time to move up to Python or R.